# how to add a project to TFS using clc

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

So the company i'm working for wants to use TFS, which is great and all but they're using android studio for their android app.
Which offers no support for TFS whatsoever (you need intellij IDEA ultimate for that)...

This means that the only option I have is to try and do everything from the commandline tool. Only problem is, it isn't working.

I've attempted to follow the tiny tutorial on microsoft's website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092.aspx)
to no avail.

the URL where the project is supposed to go is
https://COMPANY.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Android/Dev

Here's what I've done so far:

- enabled alternate credentials
- created a local workspace (at least i think i did) by executing this command:
  tf workspace -new android -collection:URL/DefaultCollection
  (this seems to work allthough i can't verify)
- then there's the workfold command: tf workfold -map $/Android/Dev -workspace:android \Users\thierry laptop\Documents\3nm\androidProjec
  t this i'm not sure if it worked, sometimes it does sometimes it complains about the stupid command needing 0 1 or 2 arguments...

And that's it. That's all I can get to work. For every other command I get some sort of error about it being unable to detect the local workspace even though my current path is located right there to complaining about not finding the server even though I defined the URL.

Can anyone help me to get the project uploaded and TFS running?

Comment: Is there some reason that you are not using Git in TFS? Git would integrate much more effectively than TFVC.

Comment: What is the output from "tf workspaces"

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible to use git because I did try but I couldn't access the repo through git.
I'll have to check on monday though for both git and the output.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution but in the end I had to install ms VS 2015 anyway so I'm now using the build in TFS support. Not the best solution but definitely the easiest.
So as far as I'm concerned this question can be closed. Good luck for anyone with the same problem.